# Passing argument between Activities - null

Tags: android, android-activity, serializable

I'm sending an object of my custom class which implements Serializable:

```
public class MyObject extends ParseObject implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public MyObject() {
}
public String getTitle() {
    return getString("title");
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    put("title", title);
}
public ParseFile getParseFile() {
    return getParseFile("file");
}
public void setParseFile(ParseFile file) {
    put("file", file);
}
}
```

The class contains atm one string and one ParseFile.

I'm trying to pass an object from one Activity to another.

```
private void editMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("MyObject", myObject);  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OUT: "+myObject.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // here i get the content, proper string
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in 'receiver' activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    myObject = (MyObject)intent.getSerializableExtra("MyObject");
    if (myObject != null) {
        editText.setText(myObject.getTitle());
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IN: "+myObject.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // here is null
}
```

What am i doing wrong..? I followed another questions on SOF but that didn't help ;)
BTW: No, ParseFile is class from [Parse developers](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#files)

Comment: TO pass user define object you need to implements Parsebel interface  rather Seriazable

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Parsebel? Is it a typo(you've meant Parcelable?) or I can't find this?

Comment: plz post the code for MyObject and ParseObject

Comment: I've updated the question. Please notice, that ParseObject is a library (i've attached link in the end of question) not my object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess It should be Something like this **ParsObject implements Serializable** because according the Topic about Serializable  if the Super class is not serializable then the state of the instance is not maintained. So try to make The ParseObject class Serializable and see the result

Try Something Like this

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

private ParseObject parseObject;

public MyObject() {
    parseObject = new ParseObject();
}

public String getTitle() {
    return parseObject.getString("title");
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    parseObject.put("title", title);
}

public ParseFile getParseFile() {
    return parseObject.getParseFile("file");
}

public void setParseFile(ParseFile file) {
    parseObject.put("file", file);
}

private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
        throws IOException {
    stream.writeObject(parseObject);
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    parseObject = (ParseObject) stream.readObject();
}
}
```

Comment: I've wrote in code in lines with Toast - before sending, myObject.getText() have proper data, so it can't be null

Comment: Can u Share your Pojo Class

Comment: Please paste ur logcat details

Comment: ParseFile is an external library that i can't access. I can't make it serializable if it's not already serializable. I don't have access to the class. I surely need to use ParseFile.

Comment: Nice idea. I can't implement it this way, because there are some Parse internal problems, however I've chatted with some people and it went out, that Parse anyway caches all objects, so best idea is to 'download' it again. Anyway, i'm going to accept this answer because you've teached me something quite interesting.

Comment: @SonusinghChauhan: Aap toh dude ho :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bundle` to pass data

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
bundle.putSerializable("MyObject", myObject);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And retrieve using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
myObject = (MyObject)bundle.getSerializable("MyObject");
```

Comment: Same result, also null in toast in receiver class.

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's problem but I did find it useful to pass a byte[] and then create a parseFile in the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think your MyObject isn't really Serializable. In order to serialize a class you need 2 conditions:

- implement the Serializable interface
- all members must be Serializable

I doubt that the ParseFile is serializable so this doesn't work

Comment: Then how to pass myObject with ParseFile?

Comment: you can store it in an Application class which each Activity can access

Comment: These myObjects are fetched from the cloud and kept in array (which is refreshing itself from time to time). I don't want to keep all of them in Application because of memory management. How should i set/get these object to/from Application?

Answer (score 0):

here is my code that I am using to pass Object class between Activity:

```
public class ClassName extends Activity{

  static ClassName2 abc_obj;

  public ClassName(ClassName2 a_b_c){
    abc_obj = a_b_c;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // here you can access everything of class ClassName2
  }
}
```

//now here is the code to pass Abc class to ClassName:

```
ClassName2 objAbc = new ClassName2(); //update ClassName2 according to you

ClassName x_y_z = new ClassName(objAbc);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, x_y_z.getClass());
startActivity(intent);
```

hope it will help you. happy coding :)

Comment: Hm, won't it be very memory consuming? Nothing can be released and ClassName2 is all the time in memory.

Comment: when you are done with ClassName2 then u have to clear it from memory, and its not so complex to do this. hope who works with mobile programming they know it very well :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyObject extends ParseObject implements Serializable {
```

Here if `ParseObject` is your class? if yes try making it `serializable`.
Also check that some of the android objects are not `serializable` to ignore those use `transient`.

also use `intent.putSerializable("MyObject", myObject);` and `intent.gettSerializable("MyObject");`

Comment: No, Parse object is class from [Parse developers](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-classes)

Comment: check edited answer and it will be good if you paste Whole MyObject

Comment: as i said you need to check your objects inside class are serializable or not. may be your parsefile is not serializable